# What is the difference between Wide and Nonwide tables in SQL 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I was looking at this page on MSDN:

[Maximum Capacity Specifications for SQL Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx)

And it says the following:

> Max Columns per 'nonwide' table: 1,024
> Max Columns per 'wide' table: 30,000

However I cannot find any information on the difference between 'wide' and 'nonwide' tables in SQL 2008. If I wanted to define a 'wide' table, how would I do it?

Comment: That max column limit is 30k only if you are using `Column Set` column in your table. If you are not using `column set` column in your table then max count of sparse + non-sparse columns taken together in your table can't be greater than 1024. More details [here](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/null-friendly-using-sparse-columns-and-column-sets-in-sql-server/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Special Table Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186986.aspx)

All the info you need is in this MSDN article.

A wide table is just a table with sparse columns. To make a table wide you just add a column set to its definition.

Answer (score 4):

I would say the difference is about 28,976 columns.

Answer (score 4):

It is important to note that your total fixed and variable length data are still limited to 8019 bytes total.  Being able to do this crazy extra large number of columns is only supported in sparse tables where MOST of the data is nulls.  Otherwise you still end up with rows that exceed the 8019 bytes and end up with rowdata that won't fit, or overflow into extended row data (which is very expensive to maintain compared to normal data pages).

There is a really good book from Karen Delaney that has a ton of internal features and limits for SQL Server entitled [SQL Server 2008 Internals](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735626243).  If you are really into the low level limits and how things are done in SQL Server it is a fantastic read.  It will increase the depth of your knowledge for how SQL Server does what it does under the hood at the byte level to disk in some cases.

Comment: The statement "limited to 8019 bytes total" is not true for SQL Server 2016, see [link]https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186981(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Considering this was written in 2009, I don't see how anyone would think it was relevant to SQL 2016.  :)

Answer (score 3):

Another difference is that wide tables don't work with transactional or merge replication. See the "SQL Server Technologies That Support Sparse Columns" section here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280604(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: This reference says: "Transactional replication supports sparse columns, but it does not support column sets", could you clarify your answer and also see my relevant unanswered question http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/59476/is-it-possible-to-replicate-wide-table-in-ms-sql ?

Comment: To make a table into a wide table, you must create sparse columns and also add a column set. If you don't create a column set your table will still be limited to 1024 columns.